# Any way to derive joint probability using matrix operations?

Tags: python, matrix, probability

Suppose I have the distribution of `P(X|Y)` and `P(Y)`, and I'm trying to derive the distribution of `P(X, Y)`, namely joining `P(X|Y)` and `P(Y)` to get `P(X, Y)`.

Often we write the distribution of `P(X|Y)` in a 2 by 2 matrix, where rows representing X and cols representing Y. We write the distribution of `P(Y)` in a 2 by 1 matrix, where rows representing  Y. Notice that the assignment of unconditioned variable is in rows.

However, the `P(X, Y)` is a 4 by 1 matrix, making it impossible to be derived by matrix multiplication. Is there any way to rearrange the structure of the distributions of `P(X|Y)` and `P(Y)` such that we can derive `P(X, Y)` easily, at least, elegantly programmable?

P.S. I'm aware of the possible duplication of existing questions, but I'm new to programming with probability matters, especially things around Bayes' nets. The textbook and materials I have searched didn't include such instructions on how to code them. I'm using python for doing this job, but it's ok for answers in any languages.\

Reedit: P(X, Y) is 4 by 1 because the assignment of unconditioned variable is in rows. I have to enumerate over all the possible values of X and Y, making the number of rows 4.

Comment: numpy broadcasting will handle that like a breeze...

Comment: and why is `P(X,Y)` 4 by 1? you probably need to explain...

Comment: I reedited to explain the reason why `P(X, Y)` is 4 by 1. I'll take a look at numpy broadcasting, thanks.

Comment: well just make it 2 by 2 and it will be easy! Nothing is forcing you to have it 4 by 1...